# What is the best algorithm/library to use to detect vehicles in an image/video?

Tags: gratis, open-source, library, computer-vision, algorithms

I have used opencv to train HAAR cascade, and I implemented it with opencv-java and found out that it gives false positives and its only good for face recognition.

There is HOG descriptor, but training that with opencv need SVM.

Is there any other library/algorithm which has easier training than training HOG(there is not much available source code examples(resources)on train HOG), which is preferably implementable with Java/C#?

Comment: Please post an example picture, so that we can judge what kind of resolution/conditions you have. Also, what kind of vehicles? Personal road vehicles (cars), or also bicycles, lorries, etc?

Comment: yes, cars mostly.....I don't want pre-trained resources.......I want to be able to feed it my objects......I did it for HAAR, but haar detects false positives.